# Flash always on top in Android browser workaround?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, flash

I have a website with a simple Flash animation *behind* some text and semi-transparent images as a background. I have used swfobject to embed it and set wmode opaque to make it display correctly in most browsers.

For browsers without Flash, the user gets a static background image instead and would not know they were missing anything. However, Android users get the flash *background* on top of everything as per the known issue with how Flash content is rendered in the Android browser making the site unusable.

I have added a crude browser sniff javascript function to the swfobject code to prevent it from loading for any user agent whith 'Mobile' in it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobile') == -1)
    {
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = { wmode: "opaque" };
        var attributes = {};
        swfobject.embedSWF("Images/Layout/center_flash.swf", "flashBg",
        "1004", "502", "9", "false", flashvars, params, attributes);
    }
</script>
```

The only problem I have left is for Android users browsing with 'Mobile View' turned off as the user agent pretends to be a desktop version of Safari (I think). I do not wish to disable the Flash animation for all Safari users. Is there a way of blocking it for just Andriod users - even if they have 'Mobile View' disabled?

Possible ideas include:

- detecting the Flash version with JavaScript or Flash. Does Android use specific versions (version numbers) of Flash which are different from the desktop equivalent?
- blocking the specific user agents used by Android devices with 'Mobile View' disabled.

Has anyone come up with an effective workaround for this issue?

Your help/input is appreciated!

Comment: More about this issue on my [blog](http://peterchinkin.tumblr.com/post/21268904763/flash-on-android-on-top-bug).

Answer (score 0):

You can detect android only by checking the userAgent of the browser in your JavaScript

Something like this:

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1)
 {
     // It's android
 }
```

As far as the flash issue itself, I don't know as I never use flash :P

*edit*

You can also use that technique for other useragents (I.E. iPhone, iPad, safari)

*edit2*

Sorry, I just went on my android phone and realized the actual setting changes the userAgent to whatever the user picks (desktop/ipad/iphone/safari). That's no good then, I apologize.

Unfortunately, what you are asking is very difficult then. There are no unique identifiers in the android flash version to give you any help. And the fact that android spoofs the userAgent makes it impossibly to detect if they are on mobile or not.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but the android userAgent of my phone is "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_3; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.16" when 'Mobile View' is disabled. I think it varies depending on which phone and OS version you have. Is there something in this that can be ised to isolate such users?

Comment: @PeterChinkin I apologize, as far as I know there is no way to identify if flash is a mobile version or not on its own. (The only way is through userAgent detection, which android's browser spoofs in desktop mode). There are no unique identifiers in the userAgent plugins to identify flash as a mobile version (AFAIK). I suggest forwarding adobe support an email to see if I'm wrong as I don't work with flash very often.

Comment: @PeterChinkin And via javascript, you do not have access to make android OS calls to determine if it's android or not. So you're limited to the useragent information strictly.

Answer (score 0):

There exist services that can tell you whether a user is on mobile based on their IP.

I'm sorry to say I don't know how fast, reliable, or expensive they are, but if you must determine whether a user is on Android, that's an avenue to consider

Comment: Sorry, I just saw how old this question is, but I guess I'll leave my answer in case somebody's searching for it...